# How to know when user finished scrolling on iPad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, scroll

I'm using JavaScript/JQuery to update the content of a div that is scrollable horizontally.  I need to avoid updating the content while the user is scrolling.  In a normal browser, this is easy as the onscroll event tells me when the user has finished.

Unfortunately, it isn't so easy on an iPad. There are 2 scenarios on the iPad:

1. The user scrolls slowly and releases their finger - here a 'touchend' event will fire and that's it.
2. The user scrolls quickly and releases their finger mid-swipe - here a touchend will fire when they lift their finger, but the device will continue scrolling for a second or two using the 'momentum' of the swipe.  Once it's stopped, a 'scroll' event will fire.

The problem is, there's no way of knowing that scenario 2 is happening.  A touchend event happens in both cases and there's no way of knowing that a scroll event will be fired, other than waiting to see if it does.

To make it worse, the iPad only updates the scrollLeft property of the div AFTER the scrolling has finished (in either scenario).  So I can't check periodically to see if scrollLeft is still changing).

So how can I know that the div content has finished scrolling?